# How can I determine what permissions my user is missing for receiving a ZFS dataset?

Tags: freebsd, zfs, truenas, delegation, jail

I have a FreeNAS (11.1-U1) and a FreeBSD (11.1-RELEASE-p6) machine. On the FreeNAS I'd like to `zfs receive` recursive snapshots as a non-root user with delegated privileges. This appears to work well for most of the child-datasets. But iocage's `data` datasets, which can be mounted into the jail and administered from there, they fail:

```
root@freebsd:~> zfs send -RI "dozer@2018-02-21" "dozer@2018-03-08"  | ssh -T -i /root/backup_key backupuser@freenas zfs receive -dvuF neo/backups/freebsd
receiving incremental stream of dozer@2018-03-03 into neo/backups/freebsd@2018-03-03
received 312B stream in 1 seconds (312B/sec)
receiving incremental stream of dozer@2018-03-07 into neo/backups/freebsd@2018-03-07
received 312B stream in 1 seconds (312B/sec)
receiving incremental stream of dozer@2018-03-08 into neo/backups/freebsd@2018-03-08
received 312B stream in 1 seconds (312B/sec)
receiving incremental stream of dozer/ROOT@2018-03-03 into neo/backups/freebsd/ROOT@2018-03-03
.
.
.
receiving incremental stream of dozer/iocage/jails/owncloud/root@2018-03-08 into neo/backups/freebsd/iocage/jails/owncloud/root@2018-03-08
received 578MB stream in 110 seconds (5.25MB/sec)
receiving incremental stream of dozer/iocage/jails/owncloud/root/data@2018-03-03 into neo/backups/freebsd/iocage/jails/owncloud/root/data@2018-03-03
cannot receive incremental stream: permission denied
warning: cannot send 'dozer/iocage/jails/owncloud/root/data@2018-03-03': signal received
warning: cannot send 'dozer/iocage/jails/owncloud/root/data@2018-03-07': Broken pipe
warning: cannot send 'dozer/iocage/jails/owncloud/root/data@2018-03-08': Broken pipe
```

The permissions of that particular child are exactly the same as the one of the parent dataset:

```
root@freenas:~ # zfs allow neo/backups/freebsd/iocage/jails/owncloud/root/data
---- Permissions on neo/backups/freebsd -----------------------------
Local+Descendent permissions:
        user backupuser atime,compression,create,dedup,exec,jailed,mount,mountpoint,quota,receive,rename,reservation,setuid,userprop
```

Running the `zfs receive` on the FreeNAS as root works as expected.

What delegated privileges does my user need to receive the jailed datasets of iocage and, more generally, is there a way to make `zfs receive` give out a more detailed error message which tells you what permission is missing?

Answer (score 5):

When troubleshooting permission problems arising from `zfs` commands, analyze the `zfs` operation in terms of its component steps.

The sample command of `zfs receive -duvF` unpacks into several steps.  Two of those flags do not relate to any special permissions:

-d affects the naming of the new dataset (if any)
-v enables verbose output

The other two do.

-F means the filesystem will be rolled back to the initial snapshot of the incremental transfer before the receive starts
-u means the filesystem will not be mounted after the receive finishes

My hunch is that you're missing the rollback permission.  The -F flag in your command implies that a `zfs rollback` will be performed, and your `zfs allow` does not list `rollback`.

In the general case, one can make deductive guesses about the permissions necessary for a given `zfs` command.

The man page for `zfs` points out:

> Permission names are the same as ZFS subcommand and property names.

and ...

> Permissions are generally the ability to use a ZFS subcommand or
>   change a ZFS property. The following permissions are available:
>
> ```
>    NAME              TYPE          NOTES
>    allow             subcommand    Must also have the permission
>                                    that is being allowed
>    clone             subcommand    Must also have the 'create'
>                                    ability and 'mount' ability in
>                                    the origin file system
>    create            subcommand    Must also have the 'mount'
>                                    ability
>    destroy           subcommand    Must also have the 'mount'
>                                    ability
>    diff              subcommand    Allows lookup of paths within a
>                                    dataset given an object number,
>                                    and the ability to create
>                                    snapshots necessary to 'zfs diff'
>    hold              subcommand    Allows adding a user hold to a
>                                    snapshot
>    mount             subcommand    Allows mount/umount of ZFS
>                                    datasets
>    promote           subcommand    Must also have the 'mount' and
>                                    'promote' ability in the origin
>                                    file system
>    receive           subcommand    Must also have the 'mount' and
>                                    'create' ability
>    release           subcommand    Allows releasing a user hold
>                                    which might destroy the snapshot
>    rename            subcommand    Must also have the 'mount' and
>                                    'create' ability in the new
>                                    parent
>    rollback          subcommand    Must also have the 'mount'
>                                    ability
>    send              subcommand
>    share             subcommand    Allows sharing file systems over
>                                    the NFS protocol
>    snapshot          subcommand    Must also have the 'mount'
>                                    ability
>    groupquota        other         Allows accessing any
>                                    groupquota@... property
>    groupused         other         Allows reading any groupused@...
>                                    property
>    userprop          other         Allows changing any user property
>    userquota         other         Allows accessing any
>                                    userquota@... property
>    userused          other         Allows reading any userused@...
>                                    property
>    aclinherit        property
>    aclmode           property
>    atime             property
>    canmount          property
>    casesensitivity   property
>    checksum          property
>    compression       property
>    copies            property
>    dedup             property
>    devices           property
>    exec              property
>    filesystem_limit  property
>    logbias           property
>    jailed            property
>    mlslabel          property
>    mountpoint        property
>    nbmand            property
>    normalization     property
>    primarycache      property
>    quota             property
>    readonly          property
>    recordsize        property
>    refquota          property
>    refreservation    property
>    reservation       property
>    secondarycache    property
>    setuid            property
>    sharenfs          property
>    sharesmb          property
>    snapdir           property
>    snapshot_limit    property
>    sync              property
>    utf8only          property
>    version           property
>    volblocksize      property
>    volsize           property
>    vscan             property
>    xattr             property
> ```

The example at hand includes the `-u` flag, so the file system will not be mounted at the end of the receive operation.  However, if `-u` were absent, the filesystem would be mounted at the end of the receive process. Tellingly, the `receive` permission requires the `mount` permission.

Because a `zfs mount` operation will auto-create any necessary mountpoints, it is possible for a user to have `zfs` permission to mount the dataset, but not have filesystem permissions to create the mountpoint.  In the case of `zfs mount`, the mount will fail.  In a `zfs create` or `rename` operation, the file system will be created or renamed, but it will remain unmounted if the user does not have sufficient filesystem permissions to create the mountpoint.

Similarly, a `zfs rename` command could fail for lack of permissions at several points within the rename operation.  Loosely expressed, the component steps might be:

1) unmount the filesystem (`mount` permission)
2) create a new filesystem (`create` permission)
3) map the filesystem meta-data into the new name (`rename` permission)

A fourth step is to re-mount the newly-named filesystem at its new, possibly changed mountpoint, which again uses the `mount` permission, and possibly filesystem permissions to create the new mountpoint.

I have not tested such tricks, but it can be seen that `zfs` distinguishes between `create` and `rename` permissions, and also between `mount` and `mountpoint` permissions.  One imagines it might be possible to allow a user to create new filesystems, but once created, the user cannot rename them.  For filesystems with inherited mountpoints, renaming a filesystem often also will rename the filesystem's mountpoint, as when renaming `tank/usr/local` to `tank/usr/local.OLD` changes the mountpoint from `/usr/local` to `/usr/local.OLD`.

The separation of `mount` or `rename` from `mountpoint` permissions means that a user could be allowed to rename a filesystem but not allowed to change its mountpoint.  Or vice versa, to be able to change where a filesystem is mounted, but not be able to change the filesystem's name.

The richness of its filesystem operations and delegation of those operations, coupled with the  granularity of permissions, can make `zfs` somewhat challenging, but also very powerful.

Comment: This answer is expanded from the original.  I hope it will continue to merit its previous upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you have a snapshot where the permission is missing.

Try to set the `receive` permission on `neo/backups/freebsd/iocage/jails/owncloud/root/data@2018-03-03`.

It looks like it is set properly on the volume, but is missing on the snapshot.